# Lagrange multiplier with multiple constraint

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm taking a Statistic course, and I'm having problems with determining the support in multivariable random variables mapping.

Say we are given a multivariable function (say 2) $f(x,y)$. Given the domain of $x$ as $A \subset R$ and $y$ as $B \subset R$ and some constraint (Ex: $g(x,y)>0$). Then how do we determine the range of $f(x,y)$?

Edit: I found out that there is a similar method is named Lagrange multiplier at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier. However, in the single constraint case, Wiki said that the constraint needs to be $g(x,y)=0$. My question now would be (a) whether the Lagrange multiplier works with the constraint $g(x,y)>0$ or $g(x,y)<0$ as well, and (b) If a) is true, is the Lagrange multiplier with multiple constraints a suitable method for the problem I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question about the range of $f(x,y)$ is that it's the set of all values of $f$ corresponding to all values of $x$ and $y$ within its domain.

The  domain of $f$ is defined as all points $x$ and $y$ such that the following four conditions hold:

1) $x\in A$

2) $y\in B$

3) $x,y: g(x,y)>0$

4) $f(x,y)$ is defined (no singularities)

Lagrange multipliers can be used with inequality constraints if you introduce slack variables (See this [link](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~cajones/math2640/notes4.pdf)) in conjunction with the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).